# How to have controllers in separate file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I look around a bit and didn't find an answer that fit with my current situation. I have a app.js file:

```
'use strict';

var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', [
    // Dépendances du "module" <-- demoApp
    'ngRoute',
    'routeAppControllers',
    'todoList'
]);

demoApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 

        // Système de routage
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/contact/:msg?', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactCtrl'
        })
        .when('/todolist', {
            templateUrl: 'views/todolist.html',
            controller: 'listeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/testfiltre', {
            templateUrl: 'views/testfiltre.html',
            controller: 'demoFiltreCtrl'
        })
        .when('/testCreationfiltre', {
            templateUrl: 'views/testcreationfiltre.html',
            controller: 'demoCreationFiltreCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }
]);



var routeAppControllers = angular.module('routeAppControllers', []);

routeAppControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope){
        $scope.message = "Bienvenue sur la page d'accueil";
    }
]);

routeAppControllers.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams){
        $scope.message = "Laissez-nous un message sur la page de contact !";
        $scope.msg = $routeParams.msg || "Bonne chance pour cette nouvelle appli !";
    }
]);

routeAppControllers.controller('listeCtrl', [function(){}]);
```

I have todolist module in todolist_controller.js:

```
var todoList=angular.module('todoList',[]);

todoList.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        var todos = $scope.todos = [];

        $scope.addTodo = function () {
            var newTodo = $scope.newTodo.trim();
            if (!newTodo.length) {
                return;
            }
            todos.push({
                title: newTodo,
                completed: false
            });

            $scope.newTodo = '';
        };

        $scope.removeTodo = function (todo) {
            todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todo), 1);
        };

        $scope.markAll = function (completed) {
            todos.forEach(function (todo) {
                todo.completed = completed;
            });
        };

        $scope.clearCompletedTodos = function () {
            $scope.todos = todos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
                return !todo.completed;
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

I have my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr" ng-app="demoApp">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Demo App</title>        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.2/angular-locale_fr-ca.min.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/controllers/todolist_controllers.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-view>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <a href="#/home" class="btn btn-primary">Page d'accueil</a>
                <a href="#/contact" class="btn btn-success">Page de contact</a>
                <a href="#/todolist" class="btn btn-primary">Todo list</a>
                <a href="#/testfiltre" class="btn btn-success">test filtre</a>
                <a href="#/testCreationfiltre" class="btn btn-primary">test création filtre</a>
            </nav>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I read that I'm suppose to call, for example, my main module App and all my other module file should start with: angular.module('App').controller(...

But, this would imply that if I change the name of my app from 'app' to 'my_app' for example, I would have to go trough all my controllers and change 'app' for 'my-app'.

I would like to avoid that and just be able to import my file in index.html and just have to declare it in the dependencies of my 'app' module.

Comment: You may want to look into RequireJS. You can load other dependencies (js files) through RequireJS

Comment: @Amir, although correct, that isn't the preferred way in Angular. Using RequireJS is a pain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Angular Structure

When you build an angular app you should separate as much as possible to give your code readability. You should create a module for each page/part of your web app.

## Example

[Here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight) is an example of this type of structure, I wrote this and use it as a base for angular apps.

## app folder

This folder holds all of your components and routes.

### routes.js

This file has the states of your project and is its own module

### app.js

This file is just the base where you can call all your other modules as dependencies.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",   [
                                    'ui.bootstrap',
                                    'ngAnimate',
                                    'myAppRouter',
                                    'myAppHomeCtrl',
                                    'myAppHomeService',
                                    'myAppNavbarDirective',
                                    'myAppNavbarService',
                                    'myAppLoginCtrl',
                                    'myAppLoginService'
                                ]);
```

You can see all of the different modules written and added here. See the way this is called myApp? well we call that part in the html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

## components

this will contain things like "home" and "contact" these folders should have everything then need in little self contained html, controllers and services.

### controller/module

This is the bit that really answers your question, to add a new module for a controller you do as follows.

```
angular.module('myAppHomeCtrl', []).controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'homeContent', function($scope, homeContent){

    $scope.dataset = homeContent.getContent();
    $scope.header = homeContent.getHeader();
    $scope.subheading = homeContent.getSubheader();

}]);
```

### service/factory

So you can see that in the module we call a factory, this is also in this folder and looks like this.

```
angular.module('myAppHomeService', [])

.factory('homeContent', function(){
  return {
    getHeader: function(){
        return "Welcome Human";
    },
    getSubheader: function(){
        return "To Joe's Awesome Website";
    },
  };
});
```

## Back to index.html

So back in our index we can add all of these modules in `<script>` tags like this.

```
<!-- Angular Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/home/homeCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/home/homeService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/navigation-bar/navbarDirective.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/navigation-bar/navbarService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/login/loginCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/login/loginService.js"></script>
```

In production you will minify all these but you can just call them alll like this whilst in dev.

## Conclusion

To conclude I'll do a summery to make sure you have everything you need to get your modules to work

1. go to your app.js (main angular module) and app the name to it.
2. go to your components and create the new module
3. go to the index.html and add your script tag that links to the new module
4. now you can use the controllers and all the components as you wish

I hope this guid to angular structure helps you. Good Luck

Comment: what is 'homeContent'

Comment: @KévinDuguay homeContent is the name of my factory, its called in the controller to allow me to access homeContent functions. In this situation it just gets 2 different strings.

Comment: do I need this? Is it there just for your application? Can I make it work without it?

Comment: no you dont need it but you should put things like $http calls in a serice/factory to keep your code readable.

Comment: Thank you, it totally works and I really like the way you organize your directories. But I have just one more questions:
why is there a folder  "shared/navigation-bar", for that matter, why it as "shared/"

Comment: ah yeah thats an example of an angular custom directive that can be used throughout the whole site with just one tag. in this case its a module i wrote to drop in a nav bar.

Answer (score 4):

instead of defining the app as `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` use `angular.module('myApp', []);` var not necessary. Then in separate files like somethingCtrl.js you can define controllers like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('somethingCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);`
```

then you can add the script tags in order on html. start with the module definition first. Use [these](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules) style guidelines for angular

**OPTION 2**

define your first module. Then you define various other modules and use them as dependencies like so

index.js:

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['otherApp']);
```

other.js

```
angular.module('otherApp', []);
```

This gives you the flexibility to add all of your controllers to one module and all of your directives to another. You can mix the functionality around by using modules as dependencies. Just make sure the mainApp is loaded first in the script tag order.

Comment: Iknow, but what I'm asking is that each of my seperate files have there own module and that I can just have tomimport those file and tell to my main module in app.js that he needs my other module. I don't want to have to use the same name for the module of my external file. Like, for exemple, my app use the app module, but my todolist use the todo module.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Tell me if option 2 is the functionality that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is where [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) would help you enormously. However as your question doesn't relate to either of them you can use good ol' JS to accomplish something similar.

Take for example your `app.js` file. Build in a global config object, then use that when referencing the app name wherever you are. Then it's a case of just changing the app name in the config object to something else without breaking any other components.

```
var config = {
    app : "myApp"
}

angular.module(config.app, ["ngAnimate"]);
```

Now a controller in `controller.js` can use that same config object.

```
angular.module(config.app)
       .controller("myController", function($scope) { ... }
```

As long as you load in `app.js` first you'll have the config object available.

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controller.js"></script>
```

**This isn't pretty** and I'd advise you to use browserify or requirejs (or any other alternative) in the future to build out your front end if you want this kind of functionality without the need for horrible global objects/variables.

Comment: But, for small projects, isn't the `script` tag preferred? I mean, it's a choice, but generally?

Comment: @weirdpanda Sure, there's no need to go super crazy on front end builds for tiny projects (unless you're very comfortable with it and have a quick and easy setup ready to go)

Answer (score -2):

Say this is your directory layout:

```
├── controllers
│   └── home.js
├── directives
└── index.html
```

You define your controller in `home.js` like you usually would, and then include it in `index.html` with:

```
...
<script src="./controllers/home.js"></script>
...
```

P.S.: Using the `script` tag should be the preferred way to do this, however should you wish to use Require.js, there is a fantastic library [angularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/)

Comment: I don't understand you answer