# separate AngularJS controller files in Laravel&Angular Project

Tags: php, angularjs, angular, laravel, laravel-5.7

I try this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087682/9246297

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34729515/9246297

and then I got this error

> GET http://localhost:8000/js/TaskController.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Then I check this solution

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8371

My problem: I have a Laravel & angular Application that works fine, But I want to make the `App.js` file cleaner by separate the controllers to different files, I trying some solutions and I think they are not working for Laravel.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('LaravelCRUD', []
    , ['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    }]);


 app.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
//Some code here that works fine 
}]);
```

I also Update my `app.blade.php` files like this

```
//somecodes
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/TaskController.js') }}" defer></script>
//somecodes
```

I want to make a `StudentController.js` file that contains this controller codes.

I use these versions

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.4
Node: 8.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: undefined
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          0.7.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.7.4 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.2.2 (cli-only)
webpack                      3.12.0
```

and Laravel 5.7

Comment: i think your path is not correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34729515/9246297) that you mention is right but keep in mind that you should consider in Laravel & Angular Project is that the

`<script src="{{ asset('js/----.js') }}" defer></script>`

will provide the link to the public folder. but your the `app.js` file that you write your angular code located at the `resources\assets\js\app.js`
then you should create your `TaskController.js` into the `public/js` not in the `resources\assets\js\`.

try this code
app.js

```
var app = angular.module('LaravelCRUD', [
       'myTaskController'
       ]
       , ['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
           $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
       }]);
```

Your TaskController.js that located at `public/js`

```
angular.module('myTaskController', []).controller('TaskController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
   }]);
```

And finally, add your TaskController to your `app.blade.php`

```
<script src="{{ asset('path/ to /TaskController.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install angularjs package.

In your resources\assets\js\bootstrap.js

```
window.angular = require('angular');
```

Create a directory called *controllers* (for angular controllers) in resources\assets\js\

In your resources\assets\js\app.js (import whatever you need here)

```
window.MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [
require('angular-sanitize'),
require('angular-cookies'),
require('angular-animate'),
'ngStorage',
require('ng-csv'),
'angular-jquery-datepicker',
'daterangepicker'
```

]);

```
var controllers = require.context('./controllers', true, /^(.*\.(js$))[^.]*$/igm);
controllers.keys().forEach(key => controllers(key));
```

That's it

Now in your controller folder you can create separate folders for each controllers

Example

> ```
> -> resources\assets\js\
>      ->  app.js
>      ->  bootstrap.js
>      ->  controllers
>          ->  user
>              ->  UserController.js
>          ->  note
>              ->  NoteController.js
> ```

Inside UserController (below)

```
MyApp.controller("UserController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

   // Your Code

}]);
```

In your resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php

```
<html  ng-app="MyApp">
```

In your view blade (Something like below) Eg: resources\views\home.blade.php

```
<div class="container-fluid"  ng-controller="UserController" ng-init="init()">
```

Now run : **npm run watch** or **npm run production** (As you needed).

References:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

Comment: How I can cutomize `window.MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);` for `MyApp.controller("UserController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

   // Your Code

}]);`?

Comment: I have `ng-controller` previously in my blade. in my project it is like this `<div class="container" ng-controller="TaskController" ng-init="init()">`

Comment: Then no need to alter. just add  ng-app="MyApp" in your app.blade. Change your app.js code as i mentioned above. Assuming your laravel mix working fine

Comment: I try like this. app.js `window.LaravelCRUD = angular.module('LaravelCRUD', ['TaskController']);`

Comment: and in Task.Controller like this `angular.module('LaravelCRUD', ['TaskController']).controller('TaskController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
}]);`

Comment: I should say that my codes work if I write my controller in the app.js, but I want to separate controller files

Comment: Yes that's what i mentioned above

Comment: Create TaskController.js file inside controllers folder & inside that chnage like this   MyApp.controller("UserController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

   // Your Code

}]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184605/discussion-between-nasser-ali-karimi-and-sadaimudinaadhar).